# Is there a way to configure a custom domain so that it forwards XMPP messages to an App Engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

App Engine only allows you to use these formats for XMPP addresses:

```
app-id@appspot.com
anything@app-id.appspotchat.com
```

Is there be a way to configure a custom domain so that it forwards XMPP messages to one of these address formats.

For example, if my domain is called `myxmpp.com`, I could give that out to users as my application's JID and then forward any user chat messages received there directly to `myxmpp@appspot.com` (assuming `myxmpp` is the app-id)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that, to do this, you would need a custom XMPP server serving for your domain. I'm also fairly sure that you'd have to write said server yourself.

Comment: Any chance this has changed since then?

Comment: @SeanFujiwara No, it's definitely still the case. As far as I know, custom XMPP server support is not on the App Engine roadmap.

Answer (score -1):

This site http://www.prosody.im/doc/dns explains what you need to configure in your DNS to do this.

Comment: This only works if the server you're directing it to already expects to serve requests for that domain. App Engine doesn't handle third-party domains for XMPP, so this will not work.